# Rails - Access the HABTM middle-man's relationship data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have 3 models:

```
#Client.rb
has_many :contracts
has_many :accessories,  :through => :contracts

#Contract.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :accessories
belongs_to :client

#Accessory.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :contracts
belongs_to :pay_interval
has_many :clients, :through => :contracts
```

On my Client's `show.html.erb` view page, I'm wanting to list all the client's accessories, and the contract ID that the accessory belongs to. For example:

```
<% @client.accessories.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.name %>
  <%= a.contract.id %>
<% end %>
```

However, `contract` cannot be accessed through the accessory, only **contracts** (plural), but I'm wanting to avoid a second loop. So how can I do this?

Comment: Your model schema says `Accessory` belongs to **many** contracts; it has no single `:contract_id`.

Comment: I point this out because `a.contract.id` makes no sense in the context of an accessory, as there is no single `contract` according to your model associations.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm just wondering if there is a way to prevent having to have loops inside of loops for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `contract` cannot be accessed through the accessory

This is the point of confusion, because

```
<%= a.contract.id %>
```

makes it unclear what you're trying to do. It's not that `contract` can't be accessed through `Accessory`; its that `Accessory` **has no `contract` association**.

---

Assuming you want **the first `contract` for each `Accessory`**, you can use `.include` on the query to force a join back against your `contracts` table, avoiding the n+1 query issue

```
<% @client.accessories.includes(:contracts).each do |a| %>
  <%= a.name %>
  <%= a.contracts.first.id %>
<% end %>
```